# Se puede montar un archivo en cache con php

Tags: php, javascript, video

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el cual tengo que cargar una serie de video, el cual al buscar el archivo se demora en el cambio de video del video A al video B, esto genera un espacio en blanco, la idea que tengo es tratar si es posible el de montar la lista(me refiero  todos los videos) de video dentro de la cache para así el servidor no tenga que realizar la búsqueda dentro de este, actualmente lo que hago es cargar la lista de reproducción mediante una lista en js y a medida que va finalizando va recorriendo ese vector y extrae la ruta para buscar el video y mostrar, como mencione esto genera un retraso entre cada video y por estructura del proyecto no es viable eso.
Alguien me podría decir si es posible y como se puede realizar, de lo contrario como podría hacer para reducir ese tiempo de respuesta y eliminar ese retardo.

Nota: todos los vídeos tienen como peso de 5mb.

Answer (score 0):

hola jhonny el tema tiene que ver con el cache y que no expiren los videos, trata de precargarlos todos cuando la app se carge asi se mantienen en la cache del navegador.
tambien te dejo algunos links que de pronto te ayuden ya que no he realizado este tipo de aplicaciones no te puedo guiar completamente

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Recursos_offline_en_firefox
https://www.html5rocks.com/es/tutorials/appcache/beginner/